# Aprovar edições de, aparentemente, pessoas iguais

Tags: suporte

Já deparei com essa situação mais de 1 vez, no qual sempre acabo reprovando a edição mesmo aparentemente sendo pessoas iguais.

Como no caso [**desta edição**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/101917) [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/189602/prestashop-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0), no qual aparece a imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E se numa outra hipótese aparece somente Maria? Quantas marias existem no mundo? Qual seria a probabilidade de ser a mesma pessoa ou não? Fiquei pensando nisso?

Tudo bem que "Silva Pimenta" parece um nome incomum e a probabilidade seria menor, mas é certo como função de analista, aprovar esse tipo de edição?

Comment: Que sorte que tirou um *print* :)

Comment: Eu gosto de acessar o link da pergunta pra ver o contexto da edição :P Ver também as respostas se batem com a edição feita... acho que ver somente pela lista de analise as vezes pode gerar analises incorretas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Até concordo que há um risco de ser uma pessoa diferente, mas se é o mesmo nome, ids muito próximos, o assunto é o mesmo, faz todo sentido ali, resolve o problema que tinha no *post*, acho que dá para correr o risco que é próximo de zero. Tudo dá pra reverter se sair errado.

Convém falar com a pessoa antes de aprovar pra ver se é a mesma pessoa.

Eu acho que o que mais pesa é a edição claramente estar melhorando o *post*. Claro que você pode não ter certeza se é a intenção da pessoa, aí tem que olhar quem é para ter uma noção maior. Se parecer ser a mesma pessoa, mas a edição não é bom, aí não é para aceitar.

Eu acho que aceitar é um benefício consideravelmente maior que o possível, mas improvável, pequeno malefício.

A boa análise olhando o todo e o bom senso é fundamental. Se não tem certeza talvez seja o caso de não fazer. Talvez seja o caso de sinalizar.

Este caso tinha 3 contas e foram mescladas.

Comment: Mas e agora que "merjou" as contas, não tem como eu voltar atrás e aprovar certo? Porque eu já havia rejeitado antes.

Comment: Não, qualquer mudança que ainda seja necessária tem que ser manual.

Comment: O intuito da fila não é analisar apenas o conteudo da edição? Se eu ter que parar pra olhar se o id é próximo ou questionar quem editou se é ele mesmo, então não estou mais analisando apenas "edições sugeridas". Na dúvida, eu prefiro supor que não é a mesma, até porque, como você disse, tudo é revertido.

Comment: @diegofm o intuito da fila é fazer o que é melhor para o site. De fato o conteúdo é o mais importante, mas há casos que se analisar um pouco mais pode produzir um resultado melhor, e o resultado final é o que importa. Se fosse só para olhar o conteúdo nem mostrava quem fez.